# Convert .htaccess to web.config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config, webserver

I'm using IIS-7 and am moving a site over from a linux and apache based server environment. I know web.config does the same job as .htaccess. I'm looking to convert the following lines from my .htaccess file to a web.config file. Where would I begin?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+).(jp(e?)g|gif|png)$ thumb.php?src=../../uploads/default/files/$1.$2&size=160x90
```

Comment: I am also slightly worried about how safe your thumb.php is if you allow `../../` as a path.

Comment: Could you accept my answer or let me know how could I improve it, please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To convert rules from .htaccess to web.config you can use import feature of the IIS **URL Rewrite Module**:

1. go to **IIS Manager**
2. click you site in the tree
3. double-click **URL Rewrite** in the Feature View
4. click **Import Rules** in the Actions panel
5. paste your .htaccess rules into the **Rewrite rules** textbox and you'd see your converted rules below.

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules) about this feature.

For instance your rules are converted into these ones:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
      <match url="([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+).(jp(e?)g|gif|png)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="thumb.php?src=../../uploads/default/files/{R:1}.{R:2}&amp;size=160x90" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: @DanLee: If my answer was helpful, could you accept and/or upvote it? It has passed more that a year and this thread seems abandoned/useless for further readers unless you give some feedback.

Comment: As I don't know about web.config rules, I was searching online converter but you saved my time, thanks to you @AlexanderAbakumov and MS guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a web.config file on Notepad or edit the one you have on the root
folder and copy and paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <configuration> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <rewrite> 
      <rules> 
        <rule name="Remove index.php rule" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false"/> 
          <conditions> 
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
          </conditions> 
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /> 
        </rule> 
      </rules> 
    </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

reference: https://gist.github.com/sabbour/e49b3ac9e1438c93d5fb