# Convert Apache mod_rewrite file to IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config

I don't have good knowledge about IIS, and I need to convert the following htaccess file to a web.config to enable URL rewrite under IIS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ rewrite.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your rules could be converted into IIS **URL Rewrite Module** rules as follows:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^index.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="rewrite.php?param1={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="rewrite.php?param1={R:1}&amp;param2={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([^/]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="rewrite.php?param1={R:1}&amp;param2={R:2}&amp;param3={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744188/3345644) for further reference.

Comment: @WebJo: If my answer was helpful, could you accept and/or upvote it? It has passed more that a year and this thread seems abandoned/useless for further readers unless you give some feedback.