# web.config to .htaccess conversion rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule 1e" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Assets/(.*)$"  />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/php/Assets/{R:1}"  />
            </rule>
             <rule name="Imported Rule 0" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/php/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can i convert it into .htaccess ?
I searched for a converter but there's no one

Comment: How did none of [the existing questions](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+web.config+to+.htaccess+conversion) help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert .htaccess to web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365508/convert-htaccess-to-web-config)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually.

- Create a `.htaccess` text file.
- Craft a [`RewriteRule`](http://www.google.com/search?q=RewriteRule) for each `<rule>` set.
- The `url="^...*$"` regexp remains as match pattern.
- Whereas the `<action url=...>` becomes the rewrite target.

  - A `{R:1}` would become `$1` in the target,
  - a `{R:2}` likewise `$2` and so on.
- `<rule>` flags like `stopProcessing` are written as `[L]` in Apache rules. 
  And `ignoreCase` becomes `[NC]` for instance. (See the manual for [further flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).)

For example:

```
  #                     <action url=>
  #                          ↓ 
  RewriteRule ^...*$  /path.php?param=$1  [NC,L]
  #             ↑                            ↑
  #        <match url=>                    flags
```

Comment: i tryed but it doesn't work, is something wrong ?

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Assets/(.*)$ /php/Assets/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /php/index.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>

Comment: There's an [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39208757/edit) for your question. Neither the `<IfModule>` wrapping nor `RewriteCond` are sensible. And "doesn't work" is not a problem description. Log entries and RewriteLog are.