# IIS htaccess rule converter only importing 1 rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-10

I have a example `.htaccess` file (found [here](http://tab-studio.com/en/blocking-robots-on-your-page/)) with bad robots to block. Here's a small sample code block from that file:

```
#bad bots start
#programmed by tab-studio.com public  version 2017.12
#1 new rule every 500 entries
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} \
12soso|\
192\.comagent|\
1noonbot|\
zuibot|\
zyborg|\
zyte\
 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#bad bots end
```

Basically throwing a `403` on a URL match. I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365508/convert-htaccess-to-web-config) to see how I can convert these `.htaccess` rules to a `web.config` rewrite rule via IIS.
When I import the rules however, I get an unexpected result where no rules seem to be converted, see image below. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: That converter has its limitations. In most cases you need to manually convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly choking on the \ and the carriage return.  If you try the following you'll see it should import properly:

```
#bad bots start
#programmed by tab-studio.com public  version 2017.12
#1 new rule every 500 entries
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 12soso|192\.comagent|1noonbot|zuibot|zyborg|zyte
 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#bad bots end
```

Having said that, you might consider looking at using Request Filtering & Scan Headers instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/filteringrule/scanheaders/

Comment: Thanks. I assume you're suggesting to use request filters because that blocks requests at an earlier moment than a web.config rewrite rule.
Now my example .htaccess rules work on `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, but I see an example for IIS here that uses `User-agent` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/filteringrule/scanheaders/), is there a difference?

Comment: Not only does it operate earlier, but RequestFiltering is specifically a security module and has built-in support for explicit Status Code (SubStatusCode) logging when it blocks something.  HTTP_USER_AGENT and User-Agent will be the same thing.  HTTP_ is how systems reference the data as an HTTP Header, but ultimately is just a copy of the value in the actual HTTP Header.  Under the covers they are both checking the same thing.