# Joomla site components are not working after moving site from Server 2003 to Server 2008

Tags: php, apache, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

After moving Joomla site from Server 2003 (apache) to Server 2008 (iis) all Joomla components stoppped working. What can be reason of that problem? Everything else works w/o any problems.

PHP and mysql hadnt changed.

Answer (score 0):

To run Joomla site on iis you need to install below component by using web platform installer or manually:

1)PHP
2)Mysql
3)Joomla

configure your database and Joomla setting:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-joomla-on-iis

convert your .htacess rule to URL rewrite rule if you have(install URL rewrite if nit installed yet)

refer this below link:

https://forums.iis.net/t/1167477.aspx

[Convert .htaccess to web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365508/convert-htaccess-to-web-config)

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Note: Microsft support for Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 ended.